# Datepicker plugin is not working in Jquery Query builder in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, jquery-query-builder

1. [initialization date picker plugin for columns]
   `

   ```
   let column_item: any = {
   column_name,
   column_type,
   column_display_name,
   type:column_type == "int" ? "integer": column_type == "date" ? 
     "date":"string",

   label: column_display_name,
        id: column_name,
      };

      if (column_type == "date") {
        column_item = {
          ...column_item,
          validation: {
            format: "YYYY/MM/DD",
          },
          plugin: "bootstrap-datepicker",
          plugin_config: {
            format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
            todayBtn: "linked",
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
          },
        };
      }

      tableColumn[item?.table_name].push(column_item);
      console.log(tableColumn);
    });
    this.tableMetaData = tableColumn;
    if (this.queryData) {
      this.onSelectTableName(this.queryData?.table_name);
    }`
   ```

2.[initializating jquery querybuilder in Angular 14+]

`

```
   private initQueryBuilder(columnList) {
      this.qb = jQuery(this.queryBuilderElement.nativeElement);
      this.qb.queryBuilder({
      // plugins: ["datepicker"],
      filters: columnList,
  icons: {
    add_group: "new-group-class",
    add_rule: "new-rule-class",
    remove_group: "remove-group-class",
    remove_rule: "remove-rule-class",
    error: "error-class",
  },
});
             }
```

[getting error to add bootstrap-date picker plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5Bqc.png)

[expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXkDZ.png)

https://querybuilder.js.org/demo.html